# UISegmentedControl to display different view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uisegmentedcontrol

I was just asking myself if it is alright to use a `UISegmentedControl` to pass from one view controller to another (One `UISegmentedControl` in each view controller, more precisely).

It is told in the Human Interface Guidelines document that `UISegmentedControl` may be used to pass from one view, one appearance, to another, but does not mention `viewController` as it.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear to me, but maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110567/switching-viewcontrollers-with-uisegmentedcontrol-in-ios5

Comment: See this thread [Push View Controller from UISegmentController][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630272/can-i-use-pushviewcontroller-with-uisegmentedcontrol

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use one container view controller, add some child view controllers and switch between them on segment control selection change.